# Force Browser to Not show Junk Characters

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, safari

I am attaching 2 screenshots - I have MacOS -

1. Chrome Browser, which shows many junk characters in every line.
2. Safari Browser, which does not show any of the junk characters.

So, my question is how safari managed to not to show junk characters and why all other browsers showing junk characters.

I want to force all browsers to not show these characters.

I have already tried "utf" encoding but no success. And I don't want to call a function in each and every page of my website.

I am looking for some generic solution which should be at server level.

ChromeBrowser -

[image: ChromeBrowser]

Safari -

[image: Safari]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the charset in HTML head tag.

```
...
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  ...
```

Maybe safari works because it is the default charset.

This can be the only problem. Server can't handle encoding for the browser. It's a client-side problem.